# How catch the ModalPopupExtenders JavaScript Hide call?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, asp.net-ajax, modalpopupextender

I have a weird situation where a modal popup gets hidden automatically when it is opened via JavaScript (either by doing a `.open` or by doing a `.click` on the opening button). Everything is fine when the opening button (ie `TargetControl`) is used.

To rephrase the question - what keywords should I use to search the `ScriptResource.axd` or any other script file to find the right place to put a breakpoint to?

Comment: maybe a wizard is doing it ;) but we could probably give you a more likely suggestion if you post some sample code for the MPE & Buttons that are and aren't working :)

Comment: I am sure that somewhere our own code is closing it. But I just can't figure out where... If I could put a breakpoint into the javascript I could see the callstack and figure it out quickly.
The code I would post would not exhibit the behaviour described :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out how to catch the hide call - it is in one of those generated ScriptResource.axd files. Just enable script debugging and open you page, VS will load the page and all JS files and then you can do a search for hide or for `this._hideImplementation()`.
On a separate note I still don't know why the popup is being closed but I have a hunch it has something to do with UpdatePanel.